# What is the DIFFERENCE between Snowflake Tasks to DBT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, dbt

Hi :) I'm a novice when it comes to setting up a DWH from scratch. I have chosen Snowflake as our DWH, and am now trying to set up the ELT flows.

I understand that Snowflake has a Task object, which can run SQL and be scheduled as well.
However, there is a big push from the data community to use dbt for managing the T part of ELT.

Please can you tell me what's the difference between using Snowflake's Objects of Streaming and Task scheduling to dbt.

Thank you.

Comment: Please can you clarify your question  - Streams and Tasks are completely different objects so asking what the difference between them is doesn't make much sense IMO. Have you read the  Snowflake documentation?

Comment: Yes, I thought tasks allow you to schedule transformations based on data that is ingested. I've read the documentation,  but evidently from your answer I'm confused.  Please could you explain a little

Comment: A Task is an object that can be scheduled to run either a SQL statement or a Stored Procedure. A Stream captures changes made to data in a table i.e. it is a mechanism for implementing CDC

Comment: Your question still doesn’t make much sense. DBT and Snowflake tasks are completely different tools that do completely different things. Even if you were asking what’s the difference between using dbt and a Snowflake-only solution, you’d be asking for peoples opinions which is not permitted on this site and the answer would require an essay to provide a useful opinion

Answer (score 1):

Here are two good links that explain why dbt is so great for data transformation tasks.

If I should sum it up:

- Modularity (models, references, lineage)
- Environments (development, deploy, scheduling)
- Quality maintenance (version control (GitHub) & collaboration, tests, documentation)

Links
DBT's viewpoint: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/about/viewpoint
And even the Snowflake community agrees: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Don-t-Do-Analytics-Engineering-in-Snowflake-Until-You-Read-This-Hint-dbt